How to show multiple data in one month using SwiftUI's Charts library in a bar chart?
I'm working on a personal app and I want to update the code. Currently I'm using an external cocoapod's library named "Charts" to create my charts in my app (which is in Swift).
However, I could notice that I can Implement SwiftUI's native "Charts" library and implement it in my code, but I'm not proficient on SwiftUI yet.
I'm implementing different sources to achieve this (like this youtube tutorial and this other tutorial).
Nevertheless, I would like to show 3 values per month like I show in the image called "01_3BarsPerMonth"  (which was created using the "Charts" cocoapod library in the original project), but the closest thing I have achieved is as the one shown in the 2nd link I provided you (see image "02_CurrentResult") which is currently made with the SwiftUI native "Charts" library.
I have searched other examples but they have more (and complex) code that for now, I don't need and I believe that with what I have in this moment, I might get the results I want.
In the test code I'm using now (a small practice app in order to get familiar with SwiftUI's "Charts" library), this is my ViewController class:
import SwiftUI


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        setupView()
    }


// MARK: - Setup view
private func setupView() {
    view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    
    let horizontalConstraint: CGFloat = 10
    //let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: SavingsHistory())
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: OrdersHistory())
    
    guard let savingsView = controller.view else { return }
    
    savingsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(savingsView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        savingsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        savingsView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        savingsView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: horizontalConstraint),
        savingsView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -horizontalConstraint)
    ])
}
}

And this is the code of my struct:
import SwiftUI
import Charts


struct Order: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var amount: Int
    var day: Int
}


struct OrdersHistory: View {
    var ordersWeekOne: [Order] = [
        Order(amount: 10, day: 1),
        Order(amount: 7, day: 2),
        Order(amount: 4, day: 3),
        Order(amount: 13, day: 4),
        Order(amount: 19, day: 5),
        Order(amount: 6, day: 6),
        Order(amount: 16, day: 7)
    ]
    var ordersWeekTwo: [Order] = [
        Order(amount: 20, day: 1),
        Order(amount: 14, day: 2),
        Order(amount: 8, day: 3),
        Order(amount: 26, day: 4),
        Order(amount: 27, day: 5),
        Order(amount: 12, day: 6),
        Order(amount: 32, day: 7)
    ]
    var ordersWeekThree: [Order] = [
        Order(amount: 5, day: 1),
        Order(amount: 3, day: 2),
        Order(amount: 2, day: 3),
        Order(amount: 7, day: 4),
        Order(amount: 10, day: 5),
        Order(amount: 3, day: 6),
        Order(amount: 8, day: 7)
    ]

var body: some View {
    Chart {
        ForEach(ordersWeekOne, id: \.id) { order in
            LineMark(
                x: PlottableValue.value("Week 1", order.day),
                y: PlottableValue.value("Orders 1", order.amount),
                series: .value("Week", "One")
            )
            .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
        }
        
        ForEach(ordersWeekTwo, id: \.id) { order in
            LineMark(
                x: PlottableValue.value("Week 2", order.day),
                y: PlottableValue.value("Orders 2", order.amount)
                ,
                series: .value("Week", "Two")
            )
            .foregroundStyle(Color.green)
        }
        
        ForEach(ordersWeekThree, id: \.id) { order in
            LineMark(
                x: PlottableValue.value("Week 3", order.day),
                y: PlottableValue.value("Orders 3", order.amount)
                ,
                series: .value("Week", "Three")
            )
            .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
        }
    }
}
}

I've tried modifying the example above but I always get an error complaint such as "[OrdersHistory] must conform to Identifiable" or something like that when I try to create an object of type [[OrdersHistory]].
What can I modify to get a result as in the first image (3 values for the month of January, for instance).
I appreciate your feedback.
Kind regards.

This is very confusing. Your original code makes a bar chart, but the SwiftUI code makes a line chart? For a line chart, the result looks correct to me. Do you want a line chart or a bar chart?

Hello Sweeper. Thanks for the question. What I am looking to do using the SwiftUI's Charts library, is to create a barchart similar to the "Irradiances on flat surface" image that I shared in my 1st question.
So, in my practice code, where I have 3 arrays with data (ordersWeekOne, ordersWeekTwo and ordersWeekThree) and I would like to make a chart using that data, and the barchart has to look as the image previously mentioned.
If I change the linechart to barchart, I get a stacked barchart and that's not what I need.
I hope I have clarified your confusion.
Kind regards.

I see. It seems like you just need to pass .unstacked to the stacking: parameter of BarMark.init then.

Hi Sweeper. I tried it already but it shows a stacked barchart, where the red bar (corresponding to the "ordersWeekOne" array) 'disappears'. Thanks again for your reply.

I would start by refactoring your Order type to include the week number
struct Order: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var week: Int
    var amount: Int
    var day: Int
}

Then you can have a single array as the data source
var orders: [Order] = [
    Order(week: 1, amount: 10, day: 1),
    Order(week: 1, amount: 7, day: 2),
    ...
    Order(week: 3, amount: 3, day: 6),
    Order(week: 3, amount: 8, day: 7)
]

Then we need to use strings for our labels/groups instead of Int
extension Order {
    var weekLabel: String {
        "\(week)"
    }

    var dayLabel: String {
        Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols[day-1]
    }
}

And now we can use those labels and the array for the chart
Chart {
    ForEach(orders) { order in
        BarMark(
            x: .value("Day", order.dayLabel),
            y: .value("Amount", order.amount)
        )
        .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Week", order.weekLabel))
        .position(by: .value("Week", order.weekLabel))
    }

}


If you want to work with the 3 different arrays you can join them into an array of arrays
let ordersWeek: [[Order]] = [
    [
        Order(amount: 10, day: 1),
        Order(amount: 7, day: 2),
        //...
    ], [
        Order(amount: 20, day: 1),
        Order(amount: 14, day: 2),
        //...
    ], [
        Order(amount: 5, day: 1),
        Order(amount: 3, day: 2),
        //...
    ]
]

And then use stacking as suggested by @Sweeper
Chart {
    ForEach(ordersWeek.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        ForEach(ordersWeek[index]) { order in
            BarMark(
                x: .value("Day", order.dayLabel),
                y: .value("Amount", order.amount),
                stacking: MarkStackingMethod.standard)
            .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Week", "\(index + 1)"))
            .position(by: .value("Week", "\(index)"))
        }
    }
}

An alternative way to creating the array of arrays from the original array properties is to use a computed property:
var ordersWeek: [[Order]] {
    [ordersWeekOne, ordersWeekTwo, ordersWeekThree]
}


Hello Joakim. Thank you for your possible response.

It indeed is one way to get the result I want. However, I would also like to know how to do it using the 3 arrays that I originally posted in the question. I know that I would need to use a nested ForEach (as from the more complex examples that I have seen and mentioned in the original question before). You know, to get "more weapons" using that shared knowledge from the ones who know more, like your case.
I'm more proficient using UIKit, SwiftUI is not my stronghold, but I'm currently learning it.
Thanks again for any possible help

@J_A_F_Casillas Answer updated with an alternative solution

Thanks @Joakim and Sweepers for your collaboration. I made some slight changes (like making "day: String" instead of "day: Int" in the "struct Order: Identifiable" struct), but with the code that you have kindly provided, I was able to achieve what I wanted. Thank you very much :)

One last question: how can I modify/customize the color of the charts? I tried using
.chartForegroundStyleScale([
"Week 1": .green, "Week 2": .red, "Week 3": .blue
])
after the Chart { line but it does not work.
Thanks again.

Research the chartForegroundStyleScale modifier for Chart

@J_A_F_Casillas Don't forget to accept the answer since it helped you achieve what you wanted.
